# Azure Template Deployment: What does "ContentLink cannot be null" mean?

Tags: powershell, azure, templates, deployment

I'm deploying a resource group to Azure consisting of a VM, a network, an Automation Account with some runbooks, among other things, using a JSON Template.

I'm getting the following errors,

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 4:49:23 PM - Resource
>   Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks
>   'DeployAutomationName/AzureClassicAutomationTutorial' failed with
>   message '{   "code": "BadRequest",   "message":
>   "{\"Message\":\"**Invalid argument specified. Argument contentLink
>   cannot be null**.\"}"

As well as:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 4:49:23 PM - Resource
>   Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules
>   'DeployAutomationName/Microsoft.WSMan.Management' failed with message
>   '{   "code": "BadRequest",   "message": "{\"Message\":\"**The
>   ContentLink property must be supplied in PUT or re-PUT operations**.\"}"
>   }'

These two errors repeat for all sorts of different "Assets" ( I think that's the term) of my automation account.  So for `modules`, `runbooks`, `certificates`, and `connections`.

What is a contenLink, and how can I make sure it's not Null?  "ContentLink" apppears nowhere in my template, nor can I found any explanation on the internet of what exactly a contentLink is, besides [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.automation.models.contentlink.aspx).  Furthermore, I'm assuming that "PUT" or "re-PUT" is part of the rest API that delivers the template, and I have no direct control over this process either.  **Of what use is an error message that describes problems I have no direct control over?**

This problem is synonymous with many of the difficulties I've had succesfully troubleshooting Azure templates: the error messages I get seem to be describing **Azure Internals** that I have no understanding of nor access too.  How can I troubleshoot or debug when I don't have access to the code that is actually throwing these exception, nor the explanation of what this exception means?

Thanks! [Here](https://gist.github.com/joshsvoss/4db0e9209ad2e94e7c999a747f6a8e34) is  my `template` , I would have only copied the **relevant text**, but I haven't a clue what **is**  relevant and what's **not**:

Comment: can you give a link to the template?

Comment: That way we can see it in it's entirety? Yeah let me try.

Btw are you the only person that answers Azure questions??? I feel bad that all of my issues are falling on you.

Comment: Is there any confidential information I should take out of the template, for example the subscription ID?

Comment: yeah, you can take away all of that, if you have anything hardcoded there, also, have you tried deploying with powershell\cli? ok give me some time to meditate on this now

Comment: I have been deploying using Powershell to invoke the template using the "New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment" cmdlet.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @4c74356b41 updated the gist link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after poking a little bit, it looks like you are missing the runbook content (the script itself). so your runbook resource should look like this:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks",
    "name": "[parameters('runbooks_AzureAutomationTutorial_name')]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
    "location": "eastus2",
    "properties": {
        "runbookType": "GraphPowerShell",
        "logVerbose": false,
        "logProgress": false,
        "publishContentLink": {
            "uri": "[variables('scriptUri')]",
            "version": "1.0.0.0"
        }
    },
    "resources": [],
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', parameters('automationAccounts_deployautomation_name_1'))]"
    ]
},
```

and the variable:

```
"variables": {
    "scriptUri": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-automation-runbook-getvms/Runbooks/Get-AzureVMTutorial.ps1",
},
```

I can't test the whole template, as I don't have base64 values, but I believe this should solve your issue. There might be another one after this, thou ;) who knows.

Reference data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-automation-runbook-getvms/azuredeploy.json

Also, you can just remove modules from the template, as they are not required, they are all the default ones, but for them the idea is the same, you are deploying the module without giving the module data.

And you might be missing other mandatory properties here and there, looks like `Automation Script` doesn't really work well with Azure Automation yet. You might want to resort to Powershell to provision Automation Account, as that works perfectly fine.

P.S. I have no idea what the content of the graphical runbook looks like. But i'd guess, you can export it and upload to github, and it would work.

Comment: This makes sense.  Thanks again.

Comment: I still dont' quite know how to navigate the huge pool of templates and schemas to find the information I need to troubleshoot, like you did here. How did you know where to look to find out what contentLink was?  There is the resource explorer and the quickstart templates and the repository of schemas, but how do you know which resource to look in when, and how do you find what you need within that enormous resource?

Comment: well, that's the tricky part, actually, I'm planning to do a blog post on that, if you are willing to wait a couple of days, I can send you the link

Comment: Yeah that would be great.

Comment: @AllTradesJack so, just search for my blog (my nickname here + `.com`) and look for `How to work with ARM Templates without going mad`, its the latest currently. Everything I use to work with ARM Templates is there

Comment: Great title, that's encouraging that I'm not the only one going mad.

Comment: MS just reelased this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts it is very useful for ARM templates

Comment: a. its not just released, it was released in march. b. its not really usefull. c. my blog states about that